# How can i change my chart to look like column gradient fill style?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is what I did in the constructor:

```
drawPoints.Clear();
paintToCalaculate = false;
chart1.Invalidate();
Series S0 = chart1.Series[0];
S0.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
S0.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
chart1.Series["Series1"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "0.6";
chart1.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
S0.Color = Color.Transparent;
S0.LegendText = "";
area.BackColor = Color.White;
area.BackSecondaryColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
area.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalRight;
area = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(10, 10);
area.AxisX.Minimum = 1;
area.AxisX.Maximum = 30;
area.AxisY.Minimum = 1;
area.AxisY.Maximum = 120;
area.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
area.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
```

The problem is that I'm using the chart paint event to draw points and lines:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2.5f);
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (paintToCalaculate)
    {
        Series s = chart1.Series.FindByName("dummy");
        if (s == null) s = chart1.Series.Add("dummy");
        drawPoints.Clear();
        s.Points.Clear();
        foreach (PointF p in valuePoints)
        {
            s.Points.AddXY(p.X, p.Y);
            DataPoint pt = s.Points[0];
            double x = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(pt.XValue);
            double y = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(pt.YValues[0]);
            drawPoints.Add(new Point((int)x, (int)y));
            s.Points.Clear();
        }
        paintToCalaculate = false;
        chart1.Series.Remove(s);
    }

    foreach (Point p in drawPoints)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, p.X - 2, p.Y - 2, 4, 4);
    }

    if (drawPoints.Count > 1)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, drawPoints.ToArray());
    }
}
```

I wanted it to look like this style:

[image: Chart]

It should look like in the example. But since I'm using the paint event maybe it's not possible this way.

Edit tried this solution i added a new chart control for the test in the form1 designer called chart2. Then in the constructor i did:

```
chart2.Titles.Add(("Introducing Chart Controls"));

            ChartArea chartarea2 = new ChartArea("Main");
            chart2.ChartAreas.Add(chartarea2);

            Series seriesColumns = new Series("RandomColumns");
            seriesColumns.Color = Color.Blue;
            chart2.Series.Add(seriesColumns);
            Random rnd = new Random(10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                seriesColumns.Points.Add((rnd.Next(100)));
            }
            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(seriesColumns);
            dp.Color = Color.Red;
            dp.BackGradientStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.GradientStyle.LeftRight;
            seriesColumns.Points.Add(dp);
```

But no fade in/out color change. Nothing happen.

This is how chart2 look like:

[image: chart2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the gradient effect you don't necessarily have to use the Paint event. The `DataPoint` has the `BackGradientStyle` property that will generate the gradient automatically for you. It will use the colour of the `DataPoint`. You set it like in the sample below:

```
var dp = new DataPoint(8D, 12D);
dp.Color = Color.Red;
dp.BackGradientStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.GradientStyle.LeftRight;
var series = this.chart1.Series[0];
series.Points.Add(dp);
```

Here the gradient is fading out. If you want it to pass into another color set the `BackSecondaryColor` property.

```
dp.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Green;
```